# What is the difference between "recognize" and "hereby recognize"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

1. I recognize Mr. Smith.
2. I hereby recognize Mr. Smith.

My question is as follows:

a) What is the meaningful difference between the two sentences above?
 b) Do the two sentences above carry the same meaning?

Comment: Here's a dictionary entry for [*hereby*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hereby). Please [edit] to clarify your question if this doesn't help.

Comment: They're different.  1, remarks about a matter of fact -- you recall the identity of this person.  2. is a speech act, so called, which gives recognition to Mr. Smith -- if you had not said this, Mr. Smith would not have been officially recognized,  However, 1, could also be used to mean the same as 2., leaving the "hereby" implicit.

Comment: Even though some verbs such as *recognize* are normally performative without *hereby*, you sometimes use *hereby* with them to signify the fulfillment of a promise, wish, command or obligation. Thus, including *hereby* alters the status of the speaker with respect to an obligation to act, as well as the status of the thing acted on.

Comment: In the case "by handing you the mike, I hereby recognize the member from Ohio", *hereby* helps establish the mike as a token of recognition.

Answer (score 1):

The word "hereby" means "as a result of this very act of language." It alters not just the meaning of the sentence, but also the type of discourse. Because of the word "hereby," sentence 2 is what J. L. Austin termed a "performative utterance." It doesn't make a statement of fact. It's causing something to happen, like the words "I do" in a wedding or baptism.

Sentence 1 *could* be a performative utterance, but it could also just be a statement of fact. It depends on the context. Because sentence 2 has a self-referential term, it is explicitly performative.

To answer question (b), the sentences have the same meaning, but do different things.